# accessing DOM inside node using express GET method with jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom, jsdom

i want to access that button inside express get method but it says btn is not defined while i can use it inside JSDOM.fromFile

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
JSDOM.fromFile("./index.html").then(dom => {
  let btn = dom.window.document.querySelector('.btn');
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

app.listen(3000);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("./index.html", {root: __dirname})
    console.log(btn)
  });
```

Comment: You could move `JSDOM.fromFile` inside the get handler. `async/await` would simplify the code: `app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile('./index.html')
   const btn = dom.window.document.querySelector('.btn')
   // do something with the btn here
    res.sendFile("./index.html", {root: __dirname})
    console.log(btn)
  });`

Comment: it does work but when i want to change button's text content it doesnt display the new one

```
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      btn.textContent = "btn";
    })
  console.log(btn.textContent);
});
```